# Buildkite and webhook to git repo

Tags: git, webhooks, buildkite

I have a Buildkite pipeline running, but we recently changed our git repo. How do I hook the new repo to an existing pipeline?

I know you can change the repo url, but how about the webhook url?

Can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the webhook url in the GitHub Settings section of your pipeline's Settings page.

[image: Screenshot of Buildkite's GitHub Settings]

Click the **GitHub Setup Instructions** link and you'll find both your pipeline's webhook url and instructions for setting up the webhook.